# How do I mirror the environment texture?

Tags: texturing, world

How do I mirror the environment texture?

I like the results, but I need them to be on the other side. Moving on x,yx,z doesn't give me the same results.

Comment: i am not sure, but since it is an image, couldn't you just flip the image?

Comment: Obvious, but brilliant - it worked!

Answer (score 3):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but *Mirroring / Flipping* an HDRI can be done in the *Shader Editor* with the data set to <kbd>World</kbd>.

Here you can set the X scale to -1 to Mirror along the X-axis.

[image: Flipping an Environment Texture]